# docker installation issue file not found after installation

Tags: docker

I installed docker on my ubuntu 14.04. deamon is running. but when I run 
`docker ps -a`

i got this error `-bash: /usr/local/bin/docker: No such file or directory`

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the result of `find / -type f -name docker`

Comment: FYI on my Ubuntu it is `/usr/bin/docker`

Comment: Can you show output of `which docker`?

Comment: it says /usr/bin/docker

Comment: I don't understand why `docker` command resolves to `/usr/local/bin/docker`, since `docker` is located in `/usr/bin`. Do you have an alias in your `.profile` or something like that? Is it a fresh install? Have `docker` been installed before?

Comment: hmmm how can I fix it? it was a clean install

Comment: I'm getting the same error `-bash: /usr/local/bin/docker: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A quick fix can be adding a symbolic link (`/usr/bin/docker` -> `/usr/local/bin/docker`) :

```
ln -s /usr/bin/docker /usr/local/bin/docker
```

Comment: then I got this: `-bash: /usr/local/bin/docker: Too many levels of symbolic links`

Comment: If you have run the command in the deleted answer (**DO NOT RUN THIS** : `ln -sf /usr/local/bin/docker /usr/bin/docker`), then your `/usr/bin/docker` have been corrupted (the deleted answer defined arguments of `ln` in the wrong order, so `/usr/bin/docker` points to `/usr/local/bin/docker` that does not exist). So I'm afraid you have to reinstall Docker, and then run the command I gave (with arguments in the right order :p).

Comment: ok now I got this: `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?` when I check the status: `sudo /etc/init.d/docker status
docker stop/waiting`

Comment: Is `docker` daemon started? If not, start it. Is your user in `docker` group? If not, try `sudo docker info`.

Comment: Yes I run `/etc/init.d/docker start`

Comment: found this issues: ERRO[2019-01-15T16:02:49.091537567Z] 'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support loaded.  storage-driver=overlay2
ERRO[2019-01-15T16:02:49.092716333Z] AUFS was not found in /proc/filesystems       storage-driver=aufs
ERRO[2019-01-15T16:02:49.093831844Z] 'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support loaded.  storage-driver=overlay

Comment: I suggest you to create a new question for this and close this one, since it is an other issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following in your terminal:

```
dockerd
```

Explanation:
dockerd is the persistent process that manages containers. Docker uses different binaries for the daemon and client. To run the daemon you type dockerd.

To run the daemon with debug output, use dockerd -D or add "debug": true to the daemon.json file.

Reference:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are just lacking the permissions.

Try with

```
sudo docker ps -a
```

to see if it works.

If that is the case, proceed with the solution already indicated by @norbjd :
create a simbolic link to point your docker commend to the root user docker executable.

```
ln -s /usr/bin/docker /usr/local/bin/docker
```