# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon after clean install

Tags: docker

I tried to install docker on my ubuntu 14.04. After Installation I had some issues you can read them here: 
[docker installation issue file not found after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54197988/docker-installation-issue-file-not-found-after-installation)

Installation is done now but when I run `docker ps -a` I got this error:

`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

I thought okay no problem I start it. So I ran `/etc/init.d/docker start`

Nothing changed. What is the issue in this case?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE

Docker lock sais

```
time="2019-01-15T16:04:48.442161704Z" level=error msg="'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support loaded." storage-driver=overlay2
time="2019-01-15T16:04:48.443237115Z" level=error msg="AUFS was not found in /proc/filesystems" storage-driver=aufs
time="2019-01-15T16:04:48.444209277Z" level=error msg="'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support loaded." storage-driver=overlay
time="2019-01-15T16:04:48.448467742Z" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
time="2019-01-15T16:04:48.451222266Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support oom control"
time="2019-01-15T16:04:48.451238804Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support memory swappiness"
time="2019-01-15T16:04:48.451249423Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support kernel memory limit"
time="2019-01-15T16:04:48.451255189Z" level=warning msg="Unable to find cpu cgroup in mounts"
time="2019-01-15T16:04:48.451287772Z" level=warning msg="Unable to find cpuset cgroup in mounts"
time="2019-01-15T16:04:48.451337670Z" level=warning msg="mountpoint for pids not found"
Error starting daemon: Devices cgroup isn't mounted
```

Comment: Try with sudo: `sudo docker ps`

Comment: Check docker daemon logs and let me know what it says ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969435/where-is-the-docker-daemon-log

Comment: added docker logs above

Comment: Do you have any custom kernel? What is your architecture, kernel/docker version and how did you install docker?

Comment: I've got a V-Server from strato.

Comment: I have: kernel: `3.13.0-042stab134.8`

Comment: @JanGaraj any hints for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3.13 is a quite old kernel. Install latest stable stock kernel (kernel from 3.19 has support for overlay FS). The main blocker is cgroup issue. Cgroups must be available.

Other useful tips: [error starting docker daemon on ubuntu 14.04 (Devices cgroup isn't mounted)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32002882/error-starting-docker-daemon-on-ubuntu-14-04-devices-cgroup-isnt-mounted)

Comment: not sure if I can update the cernel of my v-server at strato.

Comment: I think I migrate to a newer V-Server with ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

I think your docker user is not sudoer;
1. Create the docker group.

```
sudo groupadd docker
```

2. Add your user to the docker group.

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

3. Log out and log back in so that your group membership is re-evaluated.
4. Verify that you can run docker commands without sudo

```
docker run hello-world
```

[Source](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/)